# why primefaces p:password is losing its values on page refresh

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my project I am using primefaces p:password component.Everything is working fine except one thing, when I refresh the page it loses its values.Can anyone tell what are the security reasons behind it.

Thanks friends.

Comment: The people on SO can't magically guess what your code would look like, please try to supply some code...

Comment: I think this behaviour does not depend of Primefaces, but to HTML standards instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The assumption is that password fields contain sensitive data so they won't get shown again on page-reload.
Reason for this is that the sensitive data *usually* won't get cached by the browser (depends on your settings) and therefore is not available after the request was fired. This means your password input won't be a part of your page at any time but only gets submitted to its enclosing form.

```
initial page-load:
<p:password .../>  |-- rendered to --> <input type="secret" value="" />
after page-reload:
<p:password .../>  |-- rendered to --> <input type="secret" value="" />
```

As you can see the *value* attribute of the rendered html-output is empty, when you input a password it'll only happen on client-side, when submitting the form the value is sent to the server and the client input gets cleared.

To make your input persistent for multiple requests just set the `redisplay` attribute of the `p:password` component to **`true`**.

```
initial page-load:
<p:password redisplay="true" .../> |-- rendered to --> <input type="secret" value="" />
after page-reload:
<p:password redisplay="true" .../> |-- rendered to --> <input type="secret" value="inputPW" />
```

Please be aware of the fact that after a reload with set `redisplay="true"` the submitted password will become part of the html-dom and is **easily** readable for any attacker from the html-source!

Hope this helps! Have Fun!

Comment: Your answer helped me with another problem where an actionListener="#{someBean.sqlRequest}" wasnt working by the remoteCommand Button.. after adding redisplay="true" to password everything came to life! \o/ Thankss but do you have any idea wy (in this case) redisplay option was messing up with my actionListener (an sql requester) ?

Comment: @FilipeWolve hard to say without having a look in your code. The best would be if you open a new question and link it here in the comments. Cheers!